# CompilerError: Stack too deep, try removing local variables. -

Tags: solidity, remix

i am trying to compile my contract and running into this issue: `CompilerError: Stack too deep, try removing local variables.` I am not really sure how to fix it. Below is my code that is throwing the error:

```
    function _getValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        (uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tBurn, uint256 tLottery, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getTValues(tAmount);
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 rBurn, uint256 rLottery, uint256 rLiquidity) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tBurn, tLottery, tLiquidity, _getRate());
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee, tTransferAmount, tFee, tBurn, tLottery, tLiquidity);
    }

    function _getTValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 tFee = calculateRewardFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tBurn = calculateBurnFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tLottery = calculateLotteryFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tLiquidity = calculateLiquidityFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tTransferAmount = tAmount.sub(tFee).sub(tBurn);
        return (tTransferAmount, tFee, tBurn, tLottery, tLiquidity);
    }

    function _getRValues(uint256 tAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tBurn, uint256 tLottery, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 currentRate) private pure returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 rAmount = tAmount.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rFee = tFee.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rBurn = tBurn.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rLottery = tLottery.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rTransferAmount = rAmount.sub(rFee).sub(rBurn);
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee, rBurn, rLottery, rLiquidity);
    }
```

Comment: Hi there. Have you tried removing some local variables, like the error suggests?

Comment: Aren't they all required, though. If I remove some, then other parts of the script fail.

Comment: Okay, I was assuming you'd written the contract and could edit it accordingly. If you've copied this contract from somewhere, which version of the compiler did they use originally? (Is this Ethereum or Binance Smart Chain...?)

Comment: 0.8.0 BSC. I did a fork and am trying to customize it.

Comment: Okay, it might be that your customisation has pushed it over the limit (which I think is 16 or so variables). I'd suggest compiling the original contract first, then adding your customisation up to the point that it fails. Usually the options are a) split functions into several smaller functions, b) split the contract into several library contracts

Comment: I am a little new to solidity. This is purely for learning purposes. Could you maybe post an example of how to do that so I can learn?

Comment: Instead of returning a tuple with 8 uint you can return a memory struct.

Comment: @ismael how would I do that? Can you give a code example?

Comment: @CynicalFly Just create and struct like `struct Values {
        uint256 fee;
        uint256 burn;
        uint256 lottery;
        uint256 liquidity;
        uint256 transferAmount;
    }` and return that struct instead of the tuple.